# Define a method to catch a_method[] in a class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have a lots of call to something like this :

```
User.active[0..5]
```

Which call :

```
class User
  def active
     (an ActiveRelation)
  end
end
```

I am trying to do something like this for performance reasons :

```
class User
  def active[limit]
     (an ActiveRelation).limit(limit.to_a.size)
  end
end
```

Unfortunately it doesn't work, any ideas to implement this ?

== EDIT

More cleaner :

```
class RelationWithLimit < ActiveRecord::Relation
  def [] selector
    case selector
    when Integer
      self.offset(selector).limit(1)
    when Range
      self.offset(selector.to_a[0]).limit(selector.to_a.size)
    end
  end
end

class ActiveRecord::Base
  private 
    def self.relation #:nodoc:
      @relation ||= RelationWithLimit.new(self, arel_table)
      finder_needs_type_condition? ? @relation.where(type_condition) : @relation
    end
end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could have your own special subclass of ActiveRelation

```
class UserReturnRelation < ActiveRecord::Relation
  def [] lim
    self.limit lim
  end
end

class User
  def active
     # Without knowing exactly what relation you are using
     # One way to instantiate the UserReturnRelation for just this call
     UserReturnRelation.new(self, arel_table).where("state = active")
  end
end
```

Then User.active[5] should work as expected.

EDIT: Added instantiation info. You may want to look at [Base#scoped](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/NamedScope/ClassMethods/scoped) and [Base#relation](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/relation/class) for more info

Comment: In fact, I have overwritten directly ActiveRelation. Your solution seems a way cleaner. Q : How you tell Rails to use 'UserReturnRelation' by default and not ActiveRelation ?

Comment: Ah, excellent question. Rails can be very tricky. Do you mind showing me how you are creating the relation now?

Comment: sure, in fact I chain up a lot. I use joins, custom select, order, custom where with part of sql inside but all in active relation chain. I like the idea to chain up things. :0 I also want to use the 'UserReturnRelation' in others models... For the moment, the solution in my edit works fine but it's clearly not the ideal to override whereas inherit.

Comment: You should be able to expand on the solution in my edits. Once the first UserReturnRelation is instantiated all the other chains *should* also be the same class. If you want to use your newly inherited class in all (or some) models, you should be able to override the `relation` method in those models, or in a new base model (that in turn inherits from `ActiveRecord::Base`.

Comment: I have overide ActiveRecord::Base.relation, what do you think about my edit ?

Comment: I think this is better :) It allows a model to NOT use the overrode relation if so desired.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try it as params instead of array-indices? eg:

```
class User
  def active(the_limit)
     (an ActiveRelation).limit(the_limit)
  end
end
User.active(5)
```

(note: not tested on any actual ActiveRelations...)

Comment: yeah, actually it will work, but the code is already written and a tons of times. It can be really useful to override the blabla[].

Comment: Then I'd suggest you use diedthreetimes solution to hack the ActiveRelation model :)

Comment: Or a big-ass Search-and-replace operation... ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
class User
  def active
    Limiter.new((an ActiveRelation))
  end

  class Limiter
    def initialize(relation)
      @relation = relation
    end

    def method_missing(method, *arguments, &block)
      @relation.send(method, *arguments, &block)
    end

    def respond_to?(method, include_private = false)
      @relation.respond_to?(method, include_private) || super
    end

    def [](value)
      offset = value.to_a.first
      limit = value.to_a.last - offset
      @relation.offset(offset).limit(limit)
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: IMO this method would work better if you delegated all non`[]` methods to the original relation. Perhaps via method missing. Otherwise, if you don't want to do any limiting the `active` method doesn't behave as expected.

Comment: You're right, I only considered the OP's case. I edited my answer as per your suggestion, does this look good? (I'm usually not a big user of `method_missing`)

Comment: You need to make one minor change to `respond_to?`. You forgot to call super so `respond_to?(:[])` may return false.

Comment: Ah many thanks. That's why I don't really like these methods, they can be used for all sorts of nifty tricks but I find them hard to get right.

Comment: Agreed. That's why I think inheritance is cleaner, if you can get rails to take it.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you are defining the method in the wrong class. `User.active[0..5]` calls the class method `active` in `User` and the method `[]` in whatever class `User.active` is returning, I'll assume that it is returning an array of users, and `Array` has already defined the method `[]` so no worries about that.

You may be getting confused thinking that brackets are some kind of parenthesis for passing arguments to a function while they're not. Try this:

```
class User
  class << self
    def [](values)
      self.find(values)
    end
  end
end
```

So, if you wanna use find with an arrays of ids, you may just use `User[1,2,3]`.